# why a specific test fails when test class is executed - JUnit 5 , but not when run individually

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

I have a JUnit 5 based test class with many unit tests. Each one was individually tested, but when I executed all the tests in the class - 2 tests failed
I removed one of the failed test to see if they are conflicting, but the other one fails when the whole suite is run.

The spring container/context is created at the start of the test

Individually, the test runs fine...green

Test has the annotations

```
@Test
@Transactional
```

Class level annotations

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

Does this mean, there is a bug in the code? As it passes when run individually I'm not sure I get to know the issue if I run test in debug mode.

Please can someone help - why it can happen

Comment: What I suggest is that you can introduce a function that initializes your objects, like:

@BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    this.initializeObjectNeeded();
  }

Comment: Does this mean it is test case data issue and not any threads or logic issue?

Comment: Sounds like your tests affect each other. Remember that the Spring application context is re-used between different tests, so it could be that one test modifies the state of your application in a way that makes the other test fail. Placing `@DirtiesContext` on the problematic tests would be a quick (and dirty) fix in this case.